# what is maximum possible number of binary trees for height (or depth) h

Tags: math, graph, binary-search-tree

Is there any closed form formula to find out maximum possible binary trees with height or depth 'h'. I have seen formula for total number of binary trees for a given number of nodes. But I have not seen any closed form formula for a given fixed height or depth irrespective of number of nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's employ a recurrence relation in order to find a formula. Let `n[h]` be the number of binary trees with height `h`. Then we know that

```
n[0] = 1   //An empty tree
n[1] = 1   //A single leaf
```

A binary tree of height `i` can be built as follows: Either we use a tree of height `i - 1` as the left child. Then we can choose any tree with height from 0 through `i - 1` as the right child. Or we choose a tree of height `i - 1` as the right child. Then we can choose any tree with height from 0 through `i-2` as the left child (note the `-2` in the last term to avoid counting the same trees twice). Hence,

```
n[h + 1] = Sum{i from 0 to h}[n[h]*n[i]] + Sum{i from 0 to h-1}[n[h]*n[i]]
```

We can calculate the first few elements:

```
1
1
3
21
651
457653
210065930571
44127887745696109598901
1947270476915296449559659317606103024276803403
```

If we search for this sequence in OEIS, we find [this sequence](http://oeis.org/A001699). There are some formulas at the bottom and none of them looks to have a closed form. But that doesn't seem necessary. The sequence grows so fast that the numbers exceed fixed length data types very soon. Hence, it is very easy to calculate these few numbers that can be represented with your desired data type via dynamic programming or even pre-calculate the numbers and use them as constants.

Comment: What about BST? How to find them?

Comment: @Prvt_Yadv This answer find the number of possible tree structures. How you fill in the values is entirely up to you - you can specify them to fulfill the BST criterion.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to Nico's answer (which seems to be counting the number of trees where all non-leaf nodes have *exactly* two children) but counts the number of trees where each node has *at most* two children.

Here is a Python script for calculating this number by a recurrence relation:

```
def b(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return b(n-1) + b(n-1)**2 + 2*sum(b(k)*b(n-1) for k in range(n-1))
```

Output for the first few values is: 1, 2, 10, 170, 33490, 1133870930. The sequence can be found in OEIS [here](http://oeis.org/A063573)

Comment: Yes, the idea is exactly the same except for one thing: In your formula, a node can have either one child or two children. In mine, it always has two children but they may be empty. This gives the additional option to have either a left empty subtree or a right empty subtree. That's why your sequence returns smaller results. Your term `b(n-1)` corresponds to my `n[n-1]*n[0]`. Your `b(n-1)**2` corresponds to the term that is exclusively in my first sum but not in the second. The rest is the same (except for the sum bounds, which allow empty children).

Comment: @NicoSchertler Seems like some of your terminology is slightly non-standard. A tree which consists of a single leaf is usually taken to be of height 0, as opposed to height 1 (with an empty tree, when the definition permits them, sometimes taken to be height -1). You seem to be thinking of `Empty` as a special type of node. The sequence I have actually gives bigger numbers (it yields 10 trees of height 2 vs. the 3 that yours gives). These counting questions seem to be sensitive to the exact definitions used, with OP not quite clear on what definitions they are using.

Comment: You're probably right about the definitions. Your formula gives 2 trees for a height 1-tree (root with single child + root with two children). Mine gives 3 (root with only left child + root with only right child + root with two children). The indexing might be off by 1, depending on the concrete definition of "height" ;)

Comment: @NicoSchertler I see what is happening -- in the definition I was using, 1 child is 1 child with no way to distinguish between the case that it is a left child vs. a right child (just like a human parent of 1 child doesn't distinguish between that child being an oldest child vs. that child being a youngest). You are distinguishing the two cases -  so, (after shifting by 1 to get a consistent notion of height) your sequence does give greater numbers than mine precisely for that reason. Both approaches appear in the literature.